# Why my code does not create cells for a table?

Tags: javascript, html-table, appendchild, createelement

I'm trying to self-learn JS, and i am new to this language, but i have some experience with C++ and C#. 
I'm creating a function to generate cells, in a precedently created table, with data in them, but my program doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>
        <button type="button" onclick="compile()">cliccami</button>
        <table id="a"></table>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function compile(){
            var count = 5;
            var ris = [3, 6, 3, 3, 6];
            var halfed = [true, false, true, true, false];

            for (var i=0; i<count; i++) {
                var tra = document.createElement("tr");
                var td1 = document.createElement("td");
                var td2 = document.createElement("td");
                td1.appendChild(ris[i]);
                td2.appendChild(halfed[i]);
                tra.appendChild(td1);
                tra.appendChild(td2);
                document.getElementById("a").appendChild(tra);
            }
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

I also tried to treat *tra*, *td1* and *td2* as arrays created outside the *for* function.
Can you help me?

Comment: Check the console of your browser. It will tell you the problem. If you know the source of the problem head over to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) and check the documentation on the function that throws the error.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're trying to directly append numbers and flags to DOM elements, but the DOM doesn't let you do that. You have to put them in Text nodes. So for instance:

```
td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(ris[i]));
td2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(halfed[i]));
```

But it's easier if you let the browser do it for you by assigning to `textContent`:

```
td1.textContent = ris[i];
td2.textContent = halfed[i];
```

Live Example:

```js
function compile(){
    var count = 5;
    var ris = [3, 6, 3, 3, 6];
    var halfed = [true, false, true, true, false];

    for (var i=0; i<count; i++) {
        var tra = document.createElement("tr");
        var td1 = document.createElement("td");
        var td2 = document.createElement("td");
        td1.textContent = ris[i];
        td2.textContent = halfed[i];
        tra.appendChild(td1);
        tra.appendChild(td2);
        document.getElementById("a").appendChild(tra);
    }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="compile()">cliccami</button>
<table id="a"></table>
```

There's a **lot** more to know, though, and lots of other ways you might do what you're doing there. MDN is one of the best places to learn about the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) and about [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/javascript).